# Google Spreadsheet Json & Owl Slider Integration

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-sheets-api

I have been searching for a way to use google sheets to power an owl slider, the main reason is that I want to be able to dynamically update a bunch of sliders from a data feed.

The made issue that I have is that the Owl Slider will not be able to interpret the JSon that a google sheet outputs. As per their examples [here](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/customJson.html)  and code format below.

```
{
  "items" : [
    {
      "img": "assets/owl1.jpg",
      "alt" : "Owl Image 1"
    },
    {
      "img": "assets/owl2.jpg",
      "alt" : "Owl Image 2"
    },
    {
      "img": "assets/owl3.jpg",
      "alt" : "Owl Image 1"
    },
    {
      "img": "assets/owl4.jpg",
      "alt" : "Owl Image 2"
    },
    {
      "img": "assets/owl5.jpg",
      "alt" : "Owl Image 1"
    },
    {
      "img": "assets/owl6.jpg",
      "alt" : "Owl Image 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

So my approach has been to use jquery to parse the google sheet first to create the child items and then target the owl carousel div to have slides already there for it to rotate through, each time however I am unable to get it to animate it simply sits on the first item.

I tried to get it into codepen but it is not working for me. here is a working link, in the example attached I am targeting not targeting the owl div just one i made to make the JSon was working

http://www.tmkcreative.com/test-slider/index.html

Any help or advise would be appreciated.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but it looks like your code is using the old gdata API for accessing Sheets. Take a look at the [new Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/) - there are helpful examples for accessing data in JSON format there in the samples and guides.

Comment: Thanks for that - I will have a look and see if it sheds any light :) The code does work in other contexts, it maybe to do with the order of execution of my scripts which is causing issues.

Answer (score 0):

So after some playing around I was able to get it to work, the issue was the DOM element that I was targeting with my function. The only issue I have at the moment now is that I need to populate the target div with the amount of slides that I want to pull from the JSON file, not a major issue as there will likely be a set amount that I will likely display, but it would be ince if this was completed dynamically.

```
// ID of the Google Spreadsheet
var spreadsheetID = "SPREADSHEET-KEY";

// Make sure it is public or set to Anyone with link can view 
var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/" + spreadsheetID + "/od6/public/values?alt=json";

// make JSON call to Google Data API
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {

// set global html variable
var html3 = '';

// loop to build html output for each row
var entry = data.feed.entry;
/**
** Change to descending order
** for (var i = entry.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
 */
for (var i = 0; i < entry.length; i++) {
 html3 += '<div class="owl-item"><div class="item"><a href="' + entry[i]['gsx$img']['$t'] + '"><img class="lazyOwl" src="' + entry[i]['gsx$img']['$t'] + '" alt=" '+ entry[i]['gsx$alt']['$t'] + '"></a></div></div>';  

}
 // output html
   $('#owl-demo2 > div.owl-wrapper-outer > div ').html(html3);
```